# to check if the password entered by the user is correct in 7zip

Tags: javascript, command-line, server, zip, 7zip

I would like to check if the password that was entered by the user for .7z  encrypted file is correct (even by boolean yes or no, without compressing).

can i do it and how ? 
if yes - what is the command line ?

Comment: _I would like to check if the password that..._ Okay? What's your question? Is your code not working in some way?

Comment: @B001 Nothing cannot be working. Or it can. What a paradox.

Comment: fixed my question

Comment: _fixed my question_... Please visit the help center and take [this tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.

Answer (score 0):

Not with javascript, but with UNIX shell:

```
7z t -p"$PASS" archive.7z > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo correct || echo wrong
```

Assumes password is in PASS variable, you can substitute it directly of course.

Of course, instead of relying on `echo`'ed values you can just read the ret code of 7z. Zero for correct, nonzero for wrong.

Comment: you are right ! thanks (:

Codes list :
https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/exit_codes.htm